# Fallback Metadata showing but not page specific in Joomla 3.2

Tags: joomla, metadata, global, joomla3.2

In Joomla 3.2.x I have noticed that some pages are not displaying Metadata (the whole tag vanishes) which I have set through the menu options. If I enter something into the Global Setting this will show however.

Is there a setting that I am missing somewhere? I have tried removing all Plugins from the pages, it is a straight up Single Article page.

Comment: What is your exact setup? Are we talking about a menu item which points directly to an article or are you browsing to that article from another point?
And what metadata are stored in the article itself?
Reason for the question is that the behavior is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much deliberation it seems as though this is a long standing bit of  confusion around Joomla. I have got around this by using one of the many SEO Extensions for Joomla